# Append Class array that contains other class arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I have a Notification Class array that consists of String values and 3 other Classes(A User, Photo and Video Class). I am having troubles appending the Notification Class to an Collection View. The problem is if Photo Class is empty its fails or if Video Class is empty it also fails to append. I've made all Classes optional within the Notification Class array but it doesn't seem to make a difference so I'm not sure what to do next. Help would be much appreciated please. Thanks in advance!

Notification Array

```
class notification { 
    var profilePic: String?
    var fullName: String?
    var descriptionLabel: String?
    var descriptionImage: String?
    var postID: String?
    var user: userAccount?
    var post: Post?
    var videoPost: videoPost?
    var postDescription: String?
    var date: NSNumber?

init (user: userAccount, post: Post, videoPost: videoPost, dictionary: [String: Any]) 
{
            self.videoPost = videoPost
            self.post = post
            self.user = user
            self.postDescription =  dictionary["postDescription"] as? String ?? ""
            self.fullName =  dictionary["fullName"] as? String ?? ""
            self.profilePic =  dictionary["profilePic"] as? String ?? ""
            self.descriptionLabel =  dictionary["textDesciption"] as? String ?? ""
            self.descriptionImage =  dictionary["desciptionImage"] as? String ?? ""
            self.postID =  dictionary["postID"] as? String ?? ""
            self.date = dictionary["notificationDate"] as? NSNumber       
        }
```

CollectionViewController

```
func loadData(){

   let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("notification").child(userID).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        let postId = dictionary["postID"] as? String

        Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid!, completion: { (snapshot) in
            Database.fetchPostWithUID(uid: userID, postId: postId!, completion: { (postShot) in
                Database.fetchVideoPostWithUID(uid: userID, postId: postId!, completion: { (videoShot) in

                    let comment = notification(user: snapshot, post: postShot, videoPost: videoShot, dictionary: dictionary)
                    self.notifications.append(comment)
                    self.notificationTableView?.reloadData()
                })
            })
        })
    })
}

extension Database {

    static func fetchUserWithUID(uid: String, completion: @escaping (userAccount) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let user = userAccount(snapshot:snapshot)
         completion(user)
            })
    }

    static func fetchPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String,  completion: @escaping (Post) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("post").child(uid).child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists() {
                let post = Post(snapshot:snapshot)
                completion(post)
            }else{
        // Not sure what to write here when snapshot is equal to nil

        })
}

  static func fetchVideoPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String,  completion: @escaping (videoPost) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid).child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists(){          
            let post = videoPost(snapshot:snapshot)
            completion(post)
            }else{
        // Again not sure what to write here when snapshot is equal to nil

            }            
        })
}
```

Comment: You can use `static func fetchPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String,  completion: @escaping (Post?) -> ()) {` and then in else part you can call the completion handler like this `completion(nil)` and same for other function

Comment: Thank you @3stud1ant3 for the reply. I updated my code with your suggestion but now I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on line let comment = notification(user: snapshot, post: postShot, videoPost: videoShot, dictionary: dictionary)

Comment: I think you would need to update the init of notification like this: `init (user: userAccount, post: Post?, videoPost: videoPost?, dictionary: [String: Any])`

Comment: Thank you so much it works now! @3stud1ant3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
static  func fetchPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String, completion: @escaping (Post?) -> ()) {
```

and then in else part you can call the completion handler like this

```
completion(nil)
```

and same for other function

and then

you would need to update the init of notification like this:

```
 init (user: userAccount, post: Post?, videoPost: videoPost?, dictionary: [String: Any])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code. I will take it one by one:

You are fetching the data from `Firebase` in cascade. So first you grab the `user`, than the `photo` and in the end the `video`.

In your methods `fetch(Post|Video)withUUID` you call the completion block **if** there was a result returned otherwise you don't do anything. Which means, the next method / block will never be called.

One way to fix it:

```
init (user: userAccount, post: Post?, videoPost?: videoPost, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
   // your code after
}

static func fetchPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String,  completion: @escaping (Post?) -> ()) {
  Database.database().reference().child("post").child(uid).child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if snapshot.exists() {
      let post = Post(snapshot:snapshot)
      completion(post)
    }else{
      completion(nil)
    })
  }

static func fetchVideoPostWithUID(uid: String, postId: String,  completion: @escaping (videoPost?) -> ()) {
    Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid).child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      if snapshot.exists(){
        let post = videoPost(snapshot:snapshot)
        completion(post)
      }else{
        completion(nil)
      }
    })
}
```

So several changes to your code:

1. The `post` and `videoPost` are now optional (`?`) in the completion block:
   `@escaping (Post?)` instead of `@escaping (Post)`, `@escaping (videoPost?)` instead of `@escaping (videoPost)`
2. In case you don't have a result, it will still call the completion block with a `nil` value: `completion(nil)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just updated my code with your suggestion but now I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on line `let comment = notification(user: snapshot, post: postShot, videoPost: videoShot, dictionary: dictionary)`

Comment: Change your method to optional too `init (user: userAccount, post: Post?, videoPost: videoPost?, dictionary: [String: Any]) `

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With that change it now works but it was suggested earlier from another user so I have approved there answer